# Tuple of tuples not allowed in pandas.DataFrame constructor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with pandas dataframe in python3, I tried to call dataframe constructor on tuple of tuples. It resulted in an improper constructor call error. A quick reference to documentation of pandas.DataFrame revealed that data parameter can be initialized with numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame, Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects.
I'm unable to reckon the reason for tuple of tuples being invalid and list of tuples being valid.

I converted the tuple of tuples into list of tuples, and it saved my ass.

```
batch_computer_science = ('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4') #roll number of students
batch_mechanical_engg = ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4') #roll number of students
session_2018 = (batch_computer_science, batch_mechanical_engg)

#In the actual code there are 8 types of batches with 30 students each, sorted in order of registration in the class.`

session_df = pd.DataFrame(session_2018) # This throws an error, improper constructor called.
```

I expected tuple of tuples to work, but list of tuples work, tuple of tuples don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Lists of tuples work, tuples of tuples don't work.

As of v0.23.4, [the source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L380) for the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) class indicates `list` is considered as a special case:

```
elif isinstance(data, (list, types.GeneratorType)):
    if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
        data = list(data)
    if len(data) > 0:
        if is_list_like(data[0]) and getattr(data[0], 'ndim', 1) == 1:
           # ....
```

So just use a list of tuples:

```
session_df = pd.DataFrame(list(session_2018))
```

Remember, Pandas is an API, not a programming language. The details here are liable to change without notice.